# How to port BrowseForFolder from VBScript to C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winapi, vbscript

I need some kind of dialog for browsing the local SMB network for file shares. VBScript does it like this.

```
Set application = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set folder = application.BrowseForFolder(0, "Moo!", &h250, &h12) ' &h12 sets
' Network as the root folder.
```

So I added a reference to Forms and tried to do it with FolderBrowserDialog, but to my surprise:

```
FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dialog.RootFolder = /* The Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration doesn't have
a value Network! */
dialog.RootFolder = (Environment.SpecialFolder)0x12; /* This dirty trick doesn't
work too. */
```

Then I looked for a pinvokable function in the Windows API that does this, but didn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native Windows function is [`SHBrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115(VS.85).aspx) but under .NET you should use the [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) class